# Wrapping a query in a logic statement

Tags: ee2, query, ifelse

I didn't think this would give me any trouble, but it is. I just want to run a query depending on the URL segments.

I have this now:

```
        {if segment_3 != ''}
            {exp:query sql="SELECT a.cat_id, a.parent_id, b.cat_name FROM exp_categories a, exp_categories b WHERE a.cat_url_title = '{segment_3}' AND b.cat_url_title = '{segment_2}'"}
        {if:else}
            {exp:query sql="SELECT cat_id, parent_id FROM exp_categories WHERE cat_url_title = '{segment_2}'"}
        {/if}
            ...
        {/exp:query}
```

But every time I wrap it in the IF statement, I get nothing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because of the "else". If you use else, the conditional became [advanced](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html#advanced-conditionals) and it will be [parsed](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/template_engine.html#rendering-stages) after the modules.

Try this:

```
{if segment_3 != ''}
   {exp:query sql="SELECT a.cat_id, a.parent_id, b.cat_name FROM exp_categories a, exp_categories b WHERE a.cat_url_title = '{segment_3}' AND b.cat_url_title = '{segment_2}'"}
{/if}
{if segment_3 ==''}
    {exp:query sql="SELECT cat_id, parent_id FROM exp_categories WHERE cat_url_title = '{segment_2}'"}
{/if}
        ...
{/exp:query}
```